# how I could sort by unequal in ruby?

Tags: ruby, list, sorting

I see this post for using sort comparator but how  I could sort by unequal

[ruby's <=> operator and sort method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581619/rubys-operator-and-sort-method)

I have a text

```
cat
cat
cat
cat
cat
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
stack
stack
stack
stack
stack
star
star
star
star
star
list
list
list
list
list
```

using the logic when b1 is equal a b2 put b2 to last but when b1 is unequal to b2 put b2 next to b1

for obtain

```
cat
dog
stack
star
list
cat
dog
stack
star
list
cat
dog
stack
star
list
cat
dog
stack
star
list
cat
dog
stack
star
list
```

Please help me with this

Comment: Is it necessary to get this exact output, or does the output only need to follow a rule that no two adjacent items can be the same?

Comment: What should the result be if you sort `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']`? Should it be `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']`, or `['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']`, or throw an error because two adjacent elements are equal?

Comment: In you example you have five of each word. Will the groups always have the same number of words?

Comment: The `<=>` operator, often called the "spaceship operator" is not an equality test, it's a differential test: `'a' <=> 'b'` is `-1` because `'a'` comes first, `'b' <=> 'a'` is `1` because `b` comes after, and `'b' <=> 'b'` is `0` because they're equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To satisfy the actual logic requested:

> using the logic when b1 is equal a b2 put b2 to last but when b1 is unequal to b2 put b2 next to b1

You could use old fashioned recursion

```
def process(arr)
  arr.each_with_index.each_cons(2) do |a,b| 
    if a.first == b.first then 
      arr << arr.delete_at(b.last)
      process(arr)
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

This method does exactly as described. If `a == b` then `b` is moved to the end of the list and the whole list is reprocessed until there are no events of `a == b`

Another solution that will base the output list length on the element that occurs the least in the list and does not require sorting as long as the unique element's position in the list is an acceptable sort

```
def repeat_unordered_list(arr)
  arr.group_by(&:itself).to_a.tap do |a|
    min_elements = a.min_by{|_,v| v.size}.last.size
    a.replace(a.map(&:first) * min_elements)
  end
end
```

[Example(s)](https://repl.it/J02n/4)

Comment: I think your answer is good but why not do this using sort  with custom comparator?

Comment: @diegoto [`Array#sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) will use the rocketship (`<=>`) to handle the actual sorting a custom block must still return one of (`-1`,`0`,`1`) this makes solving your problem a bit more complex as standard comparisons will not work here and you will need cat and cat to evaluate differently based on their position in the `Array`. Weighting in this manner would be far more awkward because cat # 2 must be weighted higher than dog#1,stack#1,star#1 and list#1.

Comment: You can use the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to sort in this fashion. Group the words together; Number each like word 0 - n, sort, then remove the numbers. Viola.

Comment: @dawg I am aware of how to implement but is more awkward and does not actually satisfy the logic proposed. But thanks for posting that solution for other visitors

Answer (score 4):

If your array has elements evenly distributed (not necessarily sorted).

```
arr = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
arr.uniq * arr.uniq.size #=> ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]
```

---

<sup>Caveat: if unsorted, then the first unique encountered elements during `uniq` determine the final array sorting.</sup>

Further to comments, here's a more robust solution:

```
arr = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d']
enum = arr.uniq.cycle
enum.take(arr.size)
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: While this does answer the actual question posted in an extremely concise manner, it assumes that the length of unique elements is equivalent to the number of times each element is listed (e.g. 5 words listed 5 times) but if 6 words are listed 5 times this will not perform the same.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for the feedback; I've updated my answer with another answer which is actually nicer I think.

Comment: I agree completely that is extremely elegant (I would up vote again if I could)

Comment: sagar, I deleted my answer after just noticing that it was the same as your earlier answer. My apologies, but I am a bit perplexed because I upvoted your answer earlier! I can only assume that my short-term memory has become intermittent.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ha ha! No need to apologise and thanks for the up vote!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a solution using `<=>` comparison.

But here's a way to do it:

With [`Enumerable#chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) you can group together the values that are the same (if the array is sorted; otherwise you can use `group_by` instead).

Then, you select the groups that were split based on their value and transpose that array and join the values back together.

Long story short,

```
 array.chunk{ |a| a }.map{ |k, v| v }.transpose.flatten
```

will do the right thing for the data in your example.

Note that in order for `transpose` to work, the groups must contain the same number of elements.

#### Edit:

Here's a better version suggested by engineersmnky in the comments that works even when the groups have different sizes:

```
array.chunk(&:itself).map(&:last).inject { |memo, e| memo.zip(e) }.flatten
```

Comment: If the elements are not even but still sorted and you don't mind losing the excess you could use `#inject` and `#zip` in place of `#transpose` e.g. `a.chunk(&:itself).map(&:last).inject { |memo, e| memo.zip(e)}.flatten`

Comment: @engineersmnky Your version is great! I just updated my answer. I love `&:itself` and `&:last` and will surely be using them from now on!

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
arr.group_by {|w| w}.values.transpose.flatten
```

That only works if all the groups have the same number of words. It is unclear what you are looking for if you have groups that do not have the same number of words.

If you want the groups to be defined by the shortest length group, you could do:

```
na=arr.group_by {|w| w}.values
len=na.map {|l| l.length}.min
na.map {|l| l[0...len] }.transpose.flatten
```

If you want to use a `sort` algorithm, you would probably want to do something along the lines of a decorate, sort, undecorate (AKA DSU or [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)) like so:

```
> arr=['cat']*4+['dog']*3+['list']*2+["star"]
> arr.group_by {|w| w}                     # all same words together
      .values                              # only the sepate lists of words
      .map {|l| l.each_with_index          # enumerate those so that we have [0, word]..[n, word]
      .map {|e,i| [i,e]}}.flatten(1)       # remove one level of nesting
      .sort                                # sort first on the number then on the word
      .map {|l| l[1]}                      # remove the number
["cat", "dog", "list", "star", "cat", "dog", "list", "cat", "dog", "cat"]
```

That will allow different lengths of word groups with longer groups ending up towards the front of the array.